# google cloud storage compose objects and upload the composite one

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, cloud, storage

I have to compose more objects and upload the fil e but it is not clear to me how to achieve that, I am using python.
The code should work on google cloud function.
These are the steps I have to do:
-compose a list of files froma directory,
-upload the composed object,
-set public read access to the file.

```
import csv
import json
from google.cloud import storage
from variables import *
import time
import datetime

MERCHANT_FILE_NAME = "/tmp/file.csv"
BUCKET_FILE_NAME = "feeds/file.csv"
BUCKET_NAME = "xxx-file-partial-feeds-bucket"

def set_bucket_public_iam(
    bucket,
    bucket_name: str,
    members: List[str] = ["allUsers"],
):
    """Set a public IAM Policy to bucket"""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    #storage_client = storage.Client()
    #bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    policy = bucket.get_iam_policy(requested_policy_version=3)
    policy.bindings.append(
        {"role": "roles/storage.objectViewer", "members": members}
    )

    bucket.set_iam_policy(policy)

    print(f"Bucket {bucket.name} is now publicly readable")

def compose_file(storage_client, bucket_name, blob_name_list, destination_blob_name):
    """Concatenate source blobs into destination blob."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # first_blob_name = "first-object-name"
    # second_blob_name = "second-blob-name"
    # destination_blob_name = "destination-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    destination = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    destination.content_type = "text/plain"

    # sources is a list of Blob instances, up to the max of 32 instances per request
    sources = [bucket.get_blob(blob_name) for blob_name in blob_name_list]
    destination.compose(sources)

    return destination

def list_blobs(storage_client, bucket_name):
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    return [ blob.name for blob in blobs ]
    #blob_list = []
    #for blob in blobs:
    #    blob_li
    #    print(blob.name)

def create_file_storage(storage_client, bucket_name):
  try:
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(BUCKET_FILE_NAME)
    blob.upload_from_filename(filename=MERCHANT_FILE_NAME)
    #set_bucket_public_iam(bucket, bucket_name)
  except Exception:
    new_bucket = client.create_bucket(bucket_name, location="europe-west3")
    new_blob = new_bucket.blob(BUCKET_FILE_NAME)
    new_blob.upload_from_filename(filename=MERCHANT_FILE_NAME)
    #set_bucket_public_iam(new_bucket, bucket_name)

def merge_files():
    try:
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        blob_names = list_blobs(storage_client, BUCKET_NAME)
        desination = compose_file(storage_client, BUCKET_NAME, blob_names, BUCKET_FILE_NAME)
        set_bucket_public_iam(destination, BUCKET_NAME)
        return {"result": "success"}
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

I tried this code to delete the current destination to create a new destination to compose but I get error, this is the compose_file function:

```
def compose_file(storage_client, bucket_name, blob_name_list, destination_blob_name):
    """Concatenate source blobs into destination blob."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # first_blob_name = "first-object-name"
    # second_blob_name = "second-blob-name"
    # destination_blob_name = "destination-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    destination_to_check = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    destination = None

    if destination_to_check.exists():
        print("exists")
        destination_to_check.delete()
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        destination = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    else:
        destination = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    destination.content_type = "text/csv"

    # sources is a list of Blob instances, up to the max of 32 instances per request
    sources = [bucket.get_blob(blob_name) for blob_name in blob_name_list]
    destination.compose(sources)

    return destination
```

The erre is:

```
File "/workspace/main.py", line 88, in merge_files
    destination = compose_file(storage_client, BUCKET_NAME, blob_names, BUCKET_FILE_NAME)
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 60, in compose_file
    destination.compose(sources)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 3439, in compose
    source_object = {"name": source.name, "generation": source.generation}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Hi @blob, I was able to successfully replicate your source code with a few modifications. May I know what specific error you encounter?

Comment: Hi, I only want to know how to upload the composed object.

Comment: How to overwrite the existing composed object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully replicated your error if the **composed object** already exists in your bucket.

I managed to fix it because I notice that the **list_blobs** function will return the list of objects including the **composed object** or `"feeds/file.csv"` file if it's already existing in your `bucket`. What you can do is to create a **list variable** in the **list_blobs** function then remove the `feeds/file.csv` item if it already exists in the `list`.

Below is the snippet code on **list_blobs function**:

```py
def list_blobs(storage_client, bucket_name):
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    #create a blob_list variable
    blob_list = [ blob.name for blob in blobs ]

    #Check if BUCKET_FILE_NAME or "feeds/file.csv" is showing in the list, else do nothing
    if BUCKET_FILE_NAME in blob_list:
        # If BUCKET_FILE_NAME exists, remove from the list
        blob_list.remove(BUCKET_FILE_NAME)

    # your previous code: return [ blob.name for blob in blobs ]
    return blob_list
```

Sample Output:

```
Bucket <Bucket_NAME> is now publicly readable
```